# plot Roc curve for ANN and SVM

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm using ANN and SVM for classification of 6 classes. All works well, but I'd like to measure accuracies of the classifiers using ROC curves.

I can easily get the confusion matrix for each of the classifiers but I don't know what parameter I should change to get more points and actually plot the ROC curves.

Could someone help me please!

Comment: why do you want a ROC curve? did you search? http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/37795/roc-curve-for-discrete-classifiers-like-svm-why-do-we-still-call-it-a-curve and https://m.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/w27gu/is_it_possible_to_plot_a_roc_curve_for_an_svm/

Comment: I want to know what parameter I should change (threshold)  in SVM and ANN to get more point.